# MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE URI to external storage

Tags: java, android, android-camera-intent

I am using an `Intent` to capture videos in my app. My code is similar to this (adapted from https://developer.android.com/training/camera-deprecated/photobasics):

```
File mVideo;

private File createVideoFile() throws IOException {
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS").format(new Date());
    String videoFileName = "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File movies = new File(storageDir, "Movies");
    if (!movies.exists() && !movies.mkdir()) {                 // suprisingly even this works?!
        Log.e(TAG, "could not create Movies directory");
        throw new IOException();
    }
    mCurrentVideo = new File(movies, videoFileName);
}

private final ActivityResultLauncher<Uri> requestRecordVideoLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo(), success -> {
            if (success) {
                Log.i(TAG, "successfully recorded video")
                assert(mVideo.canRead());
            } else {
                if (!mCurrentVideo.delete()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "could not delete aborted video recording");
                }
            }
        });

public void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    File videoFile;
    try {
        createVideoFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.i(TAG, "could not create file")
        return;
    }
    Uri videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, getPackageName() + ".provider", videoFile);
    requestRecordVideoLauncher.launch(videoUri);
}
```

I have a file provider registered with this path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

The major difference to the code in the developer manual is that I am using a path to **public external** storage. Thus, videos would usually be saved to the path `/storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_{DATE}{TIME}`.
Testing on different devices and emulators with different API levels (21, 30, 33) concludes that this is a legal thing to do (it does not even need any permissions to read the generated files).

From what I have read in the developer references, with scoped storage an app can still access all media files it has previously created without requesting any permission (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#storage-permission-not-always-needed). Additionally, the `File` API can still be used to access files in external storage (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#media-direct-file-native).

Do you think, it is a good idea to trust that this will still work in later Android versions? Is there any other way to easily record a video to external storage?

Comment: `createVideoFile();` We cannot see if you indead created an empty file which if you did was bad practice as the user can decide not to save the video in which case you are left with an empty file.

Comment: `an app can still access all media files it has previously created without requesting any permission` Well of course it can. But you should have told us that an app can still create video files in public Movies directory and on Android 13 devices even without WRITE permission

Comment: You told so much with so many links (that i did not follow) that it is unclear to me what you wanna know.

Comment: @blackapps I am sorry this is confusing, the point is, I can create videos (and create the Movies folder) in external storage without any permission. I cannot find any material on the Internet that says I can do so. Do you have any information about that?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/Movies/VID_{DATE}{TIME}`. You mean: `/storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_{DATE}{TIME}`?

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)` is the one you should use. And you do not have to create it.

Comment: And without knowing the Android versions you are testing with there is little to say..

Comment: `/sdcard` is a symlink to `/storage/emulated/0` whatever is the path.

Comment: Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated in API level 29.

Comment: And as I mentioned in the post, I tested API levels 21, 30, 33.

Comment: No not more. And if then also getExternalStorageDirectory().